# How do i redirect to maps page with optimizeWaypoints configuration of maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, redirect, routes, gpx

I'm using maps api in my app and when i what to see the created route i have the choice of set optimizeWaypoints = true to organize the waypoints but... I need to see that route on google maps page, but whenever i try that the way points are not "optimized".

I have done this that way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < wayptss.length; i++) {string_de_waypoints += wayptss[i] + '/';} var addresses = string_de_waypoints;

 var address2 = document.getElementById("end").value;

 // window.open("https://maps.google.ch/maps?saddr=["+address1+"]&daddr=["+address2+"] to:["+address3+"] to: ["+address4+"]to: ["+address5+"]")

        link_maps = "https://www.google.ch/maps/dir/"+address1+"/"+addresses+address2;
        window.open(link_maps)
```

The value come from here:

```
 const waypts = [];
        const checkboxArray = document.getElementById("waypoints");
        wayptss=[];
        for (let i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected) {
            waypts.push({
                location: checkboxArray[i].value,
                stopover: true,
            });
            //-----------------HERE--------------------------------
            wayptss.push(checkboxArray[i].value,
            );
            }
```

[the input adresses staff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBeyK.png)

Well... What i want to know is, if I have some way to do that like exporting directly the route to google maps or something like that.
Or if not at least a way to optimize the route waypoints array by getting his distance or something like that.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution.
I used this:

```
summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br>";
summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br><br>";
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions